# OpenGL: Turn off all lighting except what I specify?

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I'm new to OpenGL/JOGL. I'm experimenting with lighting:

```
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
```

When I disable the first line, all the objects in my scene get somewhat dark, but they still have some light. Where else could that light be coming from? (This is the only light source I have.) Is there some default ambient light that I can turn off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, there are `glMaterial(GL_AMBIENT, ...)` and `glLightModel(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ...)` which are both set by default to (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);